# When does a re-gilding happen?

Tags: clicker-heroes

In Clicker Heroes you can spend to souls to ungild a hero. It says that it will then regild a new hero in its place, but it does not imply when this will happen. Is this instant? At the end of a battle? Or does it remember which 100 + multiple of 10 level that gilding happened on and have you fight back to it for a new selection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regilding is immediate. No fight needed.

You pay your two hero souls for the regilding, then you immediately get the screen like you just gor a new gilding and you have to click to open a chest to discover your new gilded hero.

Comment: Very good to know, Cleans up the ambiguity between patch notes and UI. Thanks!